# Correcting UINavigationController orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have an array of UINavigationControllers from which I want to present in custom side menu controller. It all works but when I change devices orientation to landscape and then present UINavigationController from array which was previously presented portrait it won't rotate it will just show offscreen... Is there a way to correct UINavigationControllers orientation before showing it?

Here is how Im presenting them:

```
func presentNavigationViewController(_ navigationViewController: UINavigationController) {

    //// removing old centerNavigationController
    self.centerNavigationController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.centerNavigationController?.view.removeGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    self.centerNavigationController?.removeFromParentViewController()

    self.centerNavigationController = navigationViewController

    //// corecting view position based on status of side menu
    switch self.currentState {
    case .Expanded:
        self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = centerNavigationController.view.frame.width - ContainerViewController.centerPanelExpandedOffset
    case .Collapsed:
        self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = 0
    }

    //// and presenting
    self.view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
    self.addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)        
    self.centerNavigationController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)        
    self.centerNavigationController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Comment: How are you presenting the controllers from the array?

Comment: I've added some implementation details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive temporaly solved the problem correcting the frame right after setting

```
self.centerNavigationController = navigationViewController
```

like so

```
self.centerNavigationController.view.frame = self.view.frame
```

but i don't think its ideal solution...

Comment: This is not a workaround, but the solution. However, do not use `self.view.frame`. Instead, use `self.view.bounds`.